# Setting up .htaccess for Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess

I'm following a tutorial on Zend Framework here (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-zend2/section2.html). I barely got started, but I'm having problems setting up this .htaccess file. Under Listing. 1 in the link, there is a block of code the article says I need to create:

```
htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

php_value include_path ".;c:\ZendFramework\library"
```

How do I create the .htaccess file properly so that an index.php file, which is nothing more than just a few prints on the page, will be opened properly on my localhost? My Zend is at E:\zendframekwork\library. So far, I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

set_include_path('.;E:\zendframekwork\library');
```

As you can see, I removed the "htaccess" part (do I need that?) and rewrote the last line, but it is obviously incorrect as I still get an error when trying to open index.php. How do I write this correctly?

Also, the tutorial mentions HTTPD.CONF directives having correct paths for Zend.. I looked up my HTTPD.CONF file on Apache, but there is nothing refering to Zend. Do I need to do something about this as well?

TIA!!

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Error is ...Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script. 

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: index.php works without the htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you follow the Zend Quickstart

[Zend Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html)

.htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

Check your httpd.conf for an option "overwrite" set it to All

Comment: so it is not too important to have the rewriting rules and conditions in the IBM link? Also, could you elaborate on the "overwrite" options? I see a bunch of "override" options but no overwrites.

Comment: the rules at the ibm document are "old style" :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think, the last line `set_include_path('.;E:\zendframekwork\library');` should actually be `php_value include_path ".;c:\ZendFramework\library"`.

*php_value* is needed to tell Apache that this not for processing & should be passed on to php.